# bitbucket pipeline with c# fails

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, continuous-integration, bitbucket-pipelines

So I want to get my c# that is hosted on bitbucket to succesfully run the pipeline. Locally on my windows machine everything works fine for both release and debug build.

**First version** of the yml file:

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1

pipelines:
 default:
   - parallel:
       - step:
           name: Build and Test
           caches:
             - dotnetcore
           script:
             - REPORTS_PATH=./test-reports/build_${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}
             - dotnet restore
             - dotnet build --no-restore --configuration Release
             - dotnet test --no-build --configuration Release --test-adapter-path:. --logger:"junit;LogFilePath=$REPORTS_PATH/junit.xml"
       - step:
           name: Lint the code
           caches:
             - dotnetcore
           script:
             - export SOLUTION_NAME=GameEnhancer
             - export REPORTS_PATH=linter-reports
             - dotnet new tool-manifest
             - dotnet tool install JetBrains.ReSharper.GlobalTools
             - dotnet tool restore
             - dotnet jb inspectcode ${SOLUTION_NAME}.sln --output="${REPORTS_PATH}/jb-${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}.xml"
           artifacts:
             - linter-reports/**
```

and the .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

 <PropertyGroup>
   <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
   <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
   <StartupObject>GameEnhancer.App</StartupObject>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf" Version="3.1.0" />
   <ProjectReference Include="..\GameEnhancer.Core\GameEnhancer.Core.csproj" />
 </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Gets this error:

```
dotnet build --no-restore --configuration Release
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.2+b60ddb6f4 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.416/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets(349,5): warning NETSDK1107: Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop is required to build Windows desktop applications. 'UseWpf' and 'UseWindowsForms' are not supported by the current SDK. [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
 GameEnhancer.Core -> /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer.Core/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/GameEnhancer.Core.dll
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.416/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(283,5): error NETSDK1073: The FrameworkReference 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App' was not recognized [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
Build FAILED.
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.416/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets(349,5): warning NETSDK1107: Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop is required to build Windows desktop applications. 'UseWpf' and 'UseWindowsForms' are not supported by the current SDK. [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.416/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(283,5): error NETSDK1073: The FrameworkReference 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App' was not recognized [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
   1 Warning(s)
   1 Error(s)
```

current .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

 <PropertyGroup>
   <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
   <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
   <StartupObject>GameEnhancer.App</StartupObject>
   <GenerateErrorForMissingTargetingPacks>false</GenerateErrorForMissingTargetingPacks>
   <MSBuildWarningsAsMessages>$(MSBuildWarningsAsMessages);NETSDK1107</MSBuildWarningsAsMessages>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf" Version="5.0.0" />
   <ProjectReference Include="..\GameEnhancer.Core\GameEnhancer.Core.csproj" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility" Version="6.0.0" />
   <KnownFrameworkReference Update="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF" IsWindowsOnly="false" />
 </ItemGroup>
 
</Project>
```

Current error:

```
AssemblyInfo.cs(3,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ThemeInfoAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
AssemblyInfo.cs(3,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ThemeInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
AssemblyInfo.cs(4,5): error CS0103: The name 'ResourceDictionaryLocation' does not exist in the current context [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
AssemblyInfo.cs(7,5): error CS0103: The name 'ResourceDictionaryLocation' does not exist in the current context [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
Partial/InjectConfigForm.xaml.cs(2,22): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Controls' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
View/GameModsMenu.xaml.cs(10,22): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Controls' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
View/GameModsMenu.xaml.cs(11,22): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Controls' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
View/GameModsMenu.xaml.cs(13,22): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Media' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
View/GameModsMenu.xaml.cs(14,22): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Media' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
View/GameSelector.xaml.cs(8,22): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Controls' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
View/MainMenu.xaml.cs(4,22): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Controls' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
View/ModInfoEditor.xaml.cs(5,22): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Controls' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
View/NewGameForm.xaml.cs(4,22): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Controls' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
MainWindow.xaml.cs(8,39): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Window' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
App.xaml.cs(8,32): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Application' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
Partial/InjectConfigForm.xaml.cs(10,45): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UserControl' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
View/MainMenu.xaml.cs(11,37): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Page' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
View/GameSelector.xaml.cs(15,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Page' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
View/MainMenu.xaml.cs(22,57): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RoutedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
DialogUtility.cs(38,40): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UIElement' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
View/MainMenu.xaml.cs(41,54): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RoutedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
View/ModInfoEditor.xaml.cs(12,42): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Page' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
View/GameSelector.xaml.cs(51,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Button' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
View/NewGameForm.xaml.cs(11,40): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Page' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
View/GameSelector.xaml.cs(65,57): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RoutedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
View/NewGameForm.xaml.cs(38,56): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RoutedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
View/NewGameForm.xaml.cs(44,54): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RoutedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
View/NewGameForm.xaml.cs(51,53): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RoutedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
View/GameModsMenu.xaml.cs(21,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Page' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
View/GameModsMenu.xaml.cs(61,56): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DragEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
View/GameModsMenu.xaml.cs(95,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UIElement' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
   0 Warning(s)
   31 Error(s)
```

**notes:**
So somehow it can't use the System.Windows package.

These lines seem to make no difference:

```
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility" Version="6.0.0" />
   <KnownFrameworkReference Update="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF" IsWindowsOnly="false" />
```

Without this line:

```
<GenerateErrorForMissingTargetingPacks>false</GenerateErrorForMissingTargetingPacks>
```

The error will be:

```
dotnet build --no-restore --configuration Release
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.2+b60ddb6f4 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
 GameEnhancer.Core -> /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer.Core/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/GameEnhancer.Core.dll
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.416/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(283,5): error NETSDK1073: The FrameworkReference 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App' was not recognized [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
Build FAILED.
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.416/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(283,5): error NETSDK1073: The FrameworkReference 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App' was not recognized [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/GameEnhancer/GameEnhancer.csproj]
   0 Warning(s)
   1 Error(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

WPF is limited only to Windows OS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/19216/wpf-in-linux.html

> According to this blog(https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0-preview-1/), The .NET Core and .NET 5 (latest .NET platforms) will support WPF. But looks like the support is limited only to Windows OS.

The main problem that bitbucket pipeline is running on Linux. So, basically you are trying to build WPF application on Linux which is not supported by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

the dot net core framework is installed, but displays also:

```
NETSDK1107: Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop is required to build Windows desktop
```

inside this framework there are several 'Runtimes'for different purposes, that you can enumerate via:

```
dotnet --list-runtimes
```

in my instance i have:

```
>dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.18 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.18 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.18 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

What Microsoft do not tell you is that the csproj itself should target the correct runtime. Hence on very first line of your csproj, you should replace:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

by:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
```

and eventually add if you didnot do it yet:

```
<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
```

After you push and checked that pipeline pass, Vote! and  [subscribe to my Youtube Channel !](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVww4lxZnKGx_5I4clpb52w)